# Apple Watch Intermediary Script with Unity or Remake Game in Xcode?

Tags: unity, ios, xcode, hardware

there. I had a question that I keep finding dead ends to. Is it possible to create a Unity iOS project that has the ability to talk to a WatchOS app? I know that there's no current way to build it directly with unity but theoretically could it work if there was an intermediary script that allowed the two to talk to each other when the code is transferred it to Xcode? I'm building a game that I want to have a watch app for but I've started building it in Unity and would like to keep it there just in case for other distributions.

Otherwise I'm thinking I might have to remake the game in XCode to have that functionality.
What is the best course of action here? Try to make an intermediary script (is that's possible) or switch completely over to Xcode. I'm thankfully not too far in development that I can't switch over.
Lemme know!

Answer (score 2):

On many platforms, you can integrate native functionality that isn't built into Unity with [native plugins](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html). This [includes iOS](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html). In this case, you would need a native iOS plugin that uses the [Watch Connectivity Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/implementing-two-way-communication-using-watch-connectivity) to communicate with your watch app.

While you can sometimes find unofficial native plugins online, these are often outdated. You may need to create your own native plugin.

To be clear, a native plugin could allow your iPhone/iPad game to *communicate* with your WatchOS app. You would not be able to create the WatchOS app itself in Unity.

A tip: don't try to create and integrate a native plugin for Watch Connectivity until you've actually developed your WatchOS app. A connectivity plugin doesn't do you any good if you don't have anything to connect to.